# App Identity and Access Adapter for Istio Mixer not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud, openid-connect, istio

I am trying to protect front end applications with the IBM App Identity and Access Adapter for Istio. There are two steps to follow once the service is in place:

1. Create the OidcConfig (this is the default configuration provided in their example):

```
kind: OidcConfig
metadata:
    name: hello-oidc
    namespace: my-namespace
spec:
    discoveryUrl: https://dev-b37sro-t.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
    clientId: E3LjLlomDnaPTc0b83eZa1gT0oGDNLko
    clientSecret: randomlyGeneratedClientSecret(not revealing this one)
```

2. Create the OidcPolicy (their example configuration again):

```
apiVersion: "security.cloud.ibm.com/v1"
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name:  oidcsamplepolicy
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  targets:
    -
      serviceName: helloworld
      paths:
        - exact: /hello
          method: ALL
          policies:
            - policyType: oidc
              config: hello-oidc
              redirectUri: http://helloworld.my-namespace.my-project-host/hello
```

I am using Auth0 as identity issuer, so I generate a new application (helloworld from Istio 1.4.0) and get the parameters needed in the previous configurations from there.

For some reason, when I apply the OidcConfig and the Policy in my Kubernetes Cluster/Namespace/Service, it doesn't seem to make any effect. I am still able to access the application from the web browser without any authentication required.

These are the links I followed for the implementation:

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/using-istio-to-secure-your-multicloud-kubernetes-applications-with-zero-code-change

https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/app-identity-and-access-adapter

Comment: So you changed the OidcConfig to what is needed for Auth0? Could you share it instead of the App ID sample config? Is that config deployed to your cluster, is it active? What steps did you use to make it active?

Comment: Hi, yes, i will modify the configuration is the main question. The config and policy are deployed in the cluster, and `security.cloud.ibm.com/v1` API is active. I followed this guideline: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/app-identity-and-access-adapter#installing-the-adapter
The adapter is also deployed and stable in my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set `global.disablePolicyChecks` to `false` and did you enable mixer during Istio install?

Mixer is disabled by default now.

See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#mixer-options

Update:

I was just able to resolve this issue on my setup by doing the following:

First check the status of `disablePolicyCheck`:

```
kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath="{@.data.mesh}" | grep disablePolicyChecks
```

If this returns `disablePolicyChecks: true` run

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.disablePolicyChecks=false \
 --set values.mixer.policy.enabled=true \
 --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true
```

Running the following should show the value of `disablePolicyChecks` as `false`

```
kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath="{@.data.mesh}" | grep disablePolicyChecks
```

Comment: Please paste the required information and just add links for reference as they might not be available in the future for other users.